# All formats other than 't' return #Error for Time fields in Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SQL Time Field in a Report Builder table that I would like to format. In this case, I would like to format the field in `[SlotTime]` in `hh:mm tt` format.

[image]

When I run the report, I get the following:

[image]

I tried to set the format of `SlotTime` as follows:

[image]

When I run the report, all `SlotTime` values show `#Error`.

[image]

**Notes**

1. Since the `[SlotTime]` needs to be in the right order in the table, I cannot use a `FORMAT(SlotTime, 'hh:mm tt')` in the SQL Query as this will produce a VARCHAR field and not a TIME field.

The schedule table rows start at `01:00 PM` instead of `08:00 AM`.

2. If a DATETIME field is used, the columns for each consecutive day will be staggered by 24 hours. When a DATETIME row is used, `8:00 AM` is really a row for `2023-08-31 08:00:00`. The row for `2023-09-01 8:00 AM` will not be side-by-side with the row for `2023-08-31 08:00:00`. You will have to scroll down through 24 hours or row entries to see the next day.
3. A small snippet of the `SlotDate`, `SlotTime`, and `SlotStatus` is shown below.

[image]

4. CAST the TIME column to a DATETIME Column works.

**Solution**

1. CAST the TIME column as a DATETIME. This will serve as the resulting DATETIMEs have year, month, and day as 1900, 01, and 01 respectively.

Comment: I think that format will only work on datetime fields, not time (I could be wrong - not tested). Does your data actually contain a datetime column or separate date and time columns? Can you show a small example of you data. I'm sure you'll be able to do this

Comment: I have added a small sample of data above. The `SlotTime` field is a SQL TIME field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way of doing this but this way does work.

I created some simple data with 3 days and 8 slots per day and added some arbitrary 'amount' column.

Forgive the awful column names...

```
declare @t table (dt date, tm time, amount int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('2023-08-29', '08:00:00', 1), ('2023-08-29', '08:15:00', 2), ('2023-08-29', '08:30:00', 3), ('2023-08-29', '08:45:00', 4), ('2023-08-29', '09:00:00', 11), ('2023-08-29', '09:15:00', 12), ('2023-08-29', '09:30:00', 13), ('2023-08-29', '09:45:00', 14),
('2023-08-30', '08:00:00', 11), ('2023-08-30', '08:15:00', 12), ('2023-08-30', '08:30:00', 13), ('2023-08-30', '08:45:00', 14), ('2023-08-30', '09:00:00', 111), ('2023-08-30', '09:15:00', 112), ('2023-08-30', '09:30:00', 113), ('2023-08-30', '09:45:00', 114), 
('2023-08-31', '08:00:00', 21), ('2023-08-31', '08:15:00', 22), ('2023-08-31', '08:30:00', 23), ('2023-08-31', '08:45:00', 24), ('2023-08-31', '09:00:00', 211), ('2023-08-31', '09:15:00', 212), ('2023-08-31', '09:30:00', 213), ('2023-08-31', '09:45:00', 214) 

SELECT *, dttm = cast(dt as datetime) + cast(tm as datetime) FROM @t
```

As you can see, in the final select statement, I have added a column `dttm` (datetime) which creates a datetime column from the individual date (dt) and time (tm) columns.

Now we have this it's really simple...

Add a matrix, drop the `dt` fields onto the column placeholder, the `tm` field onto the row placeholder and the `amount` field on to the data placeholder. This sets up almost everything.

Now swap the `tm` field in the first column and choose `dttm` instead.

So not we have columns grouped by date, rows grouped by rime but we are displaying the combined datetime (`dttm`) field for the row headers.

Finally, format the `dttm` textbox as `hh:mm tt`

Here's the final design and output.

[image]

[image]